# Why isn't my Nginx alias directive working?

Tags: nginx, centos, configuration, redirect, alias

I'm using Nginx on CentOS 7 with Ruby on Rails / Puma.  I would like for certain file paths to be skipped by RoR and be served directly by Nginx.  I created this in my "server" block for my site

```c
location /assets/lib/ {
    alias /home/rails/myproject_production/app/assets/javascripts/lib/;
    autoindex off;
}
```

However, when I call an asset like `http://www.mydomein.com/assets/lib/myfile.js`, I get a 404.  This is what appears in my logs

```
2018/05/11 15:21:47 [error] 242#0: *1 open() "/home/rails/myproject_production/public/assets/lib/myfile.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 50.240.135.5, server: www.mydomein.com, request: "GET /assets/lib/myfile.js HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomein.com"
```

From the logs, it appears that the alias isn't being invoked at all.  What am I missing in the above?  My complete configuration is below

```c
upstream myproject {
  server unix:///home/rails/myproject_production/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

# Listener for Apex Domain
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomein.com;
  root /home/rails/myproject_production/public; # I assume your app is located at this location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myproject; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    if ($request_uri ~* "(\/image\/.*)|(.*\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png)$)") {
      expires 60d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      break;
    }
  }

  location /assets/lib/ {
        alias /home/rails/myproject_production/app/assets/javascripts/lib/;
        autoindex off;
  }

  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://myproject;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `location` blocks:

```c
location /assets/lib/ {
  …
}
location ~* ^/assets/ {
  …
}
```

Now, as described in Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), Nginx checks first prefix locations, and remembers longest match. Then it checks regular expression locations, and uses a matching block if found. If none is found, then it uses the prefix match.

So, in your case, nginx first finds the first `location` block, remembers it. However, the regular expression block also matches, and nginx selects that block.

In order to change nginx selection process, you need to use:

```c
location ^~ /assets/lib {
  …
}
```

for your first location. It also means that the directives in the regular expression block are not applied to these requests.